# Como acessar belongsTo e hasOne na view? - Relacionamento 1 - 1 bidirecional

Tags: php, laravel, aplicação-web, laravel-blade

Estou com projeto com Laravel 6.0 e tem a entidade User e endereço, onde usuário tem 1 endereço, assim como um endereço pertence a 1 usuário (bidirecional).

O problema é que que listar todos endereços e na lista ter a coluna do nome do usuário, até consigo, mas não me parece a melhor forma, então gostaria de auxilio para saber a melhor forma. Segue desenvolvimento:

Model User e Adress:

User

```
public function address(){
    return $this->hasOne(Adress::class, 'user', 'id');
}
```

Adress

```
public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user', 'id');
}
```

WEb.php:: Rota:

```
 Route::get('enderecos', 'AdressController@index')->name('adress.list');
```

AdressController:: Metodo index para listar

```
public function index()
{
    $users = User::all();
    $adresses = $this->adress->paginate(5);
    return view('adress.index', compact('adresses', 'users'));
}
```

index.blade.php:: Listagem da view

```
    <table class="table" id="formCad">
        <tr>
            <td>Id</td>
            <td>Rua</td>
            <td>Numero</td>
            <td>Cidade</td>
            <td>Estado</td>
            <td>Usuário</td>
        </tr>

        @foreach($adresses as $adress)
            <tr>
                <td>{{$adress->id}}</td>
                <td>
                    <a href="{{route('adress.details', ['adress'=>$adress])}}">
                        {{$adress->street}}
                    </a>
                </td>
                <td>{{$adress->number}}</td>
                <td>{{$adress->city}}</td>
                <td>{{$adress->state}}</td>
                <td>
                    @foreach($users as $user)
                        @if($user->id == $adress->user)
                            {{$user->name}}
                        @endif
                    @endforeach
                </td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    </table>
```

Essa é a melhor forma abaixo? Poderiam me explicar ou dicas?

```
<td>
    @foreach($users as $user)
         @if($user->id == $adress->user)
              {{$user->name}}
          @endif
    @endforeach
</td>
```

Obrigado!

Comment: Preciso de ajuda neste problema e não criticas destrutivas... AJUDA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você não precisa fazer um loop no array de usuários para saber qual usuário do endereço. A relação que você criou deveria trazer essa informação.

O problema aqui é que você criou no banco de dados a coluna `user`, e usou esse mesmo nome na relação.

Tente chamar a relação com outro nome, exemplo:

Address.php

```
public function addressUser(){
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user', 'id');
}
```

Dessa forma você terá o campo `user` que vem do banco e o campo `addressUser` que será uma relação mapeada ao objeto usuário.

Fazendo isso, tente acessar dessa forma:

```
@foreach($adresses as $adress)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$adress->id}}</td>
        <td>
            <a href="{{route('adress.details', ['adress'=>$adress])}}">
                {{$adress->street}}
            </a>
        </td>
        <td>{{$adress->number}}</td>
        <td>{{$adress->city}}</td>
        <td>{{$adress->state}}</td>
        <td>
            {{$adress->addressUser->name}}
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Para as próximas relações, recomendo usar a nomenclatura que o próprio Laravel indica, que é `{nome_tabela}_id`, ou seja, ao invés de na tabela `address` você ter um campo `user`, use um campo chamado `user_id`.
Dessa forma o Laravel consegue até mesmo fazer o mapeamento automático no `BelongsTo`, então você só precisaria usar `$this->belongsTo(User::class);`. E fica melhor também pois você poderá nomear a relação como `user`, pois não vai ter conflito com os campos originais.

Comment: Olá, Phiter, funcionou perfeitamente! O problema este tempo todo era o nome do metodo, nossa :o... Muito obrigado pelo retorno e dicas!!!! :)

Comment: @RafaelBlum se te ajudou lembre-se de aceitar a resposta como a correta!

Comment: Sim :) Obrigado novamente! Só não sei porque tem uma galera ai que negativa a pergunta... Busquei estudar e conteúdo, mas sei retorno, então busquei aqui na comunidade. Ainda bem que tem pessoas que ajudam como você a galera com dificuldade... obrigado!

Comment: @RafaelBlum a comunidade do StackOverflow é meio tóxica, sempre foi, e estão tomando umas medidas pra melhorar isso ultimamente, mas ainda é um problema grande. Não são bons com iniciantes, e não ajudam quando a pergunta não está clara, preferem simplesmente fechar do que pedir pra melhorar.

Comment: Bem assim... sou novo na comunidade e sempre tive essa percepção... o intuito é ajuda e ver de forma construtiva tudo e sempre tentei colocar de forma clara, até mesmo para ajuda a pessoa a saber como funciona e ai me ajudar :). Obrigado, brow!!! :)

Answer (score 1):

Você não precisa chamar os dois relacionamentos, basta chamar um

Eu faria assim:

```
public function index(){
$users = User::with(['address'])->->paginate(5);
return view('adress.index', ['users' => $users]);
```

}

na Index:

```
@foreach($users as $user)
<tr>
    <td>{{$adress->id}}</td>
    <td>
        <a href="{{route('adress.details', ['adress'=>$user->adress])}}">
            {{$user->adress->street}}
        </a>
    </td>
    <td>{{$user->adress->number}}</td>
    <td>{{$user->$adress->city}}</td>
    <td>{{$user->$adress->state}}</td>
    <td>
        {{$user->->name}}
    </td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

Caso vc queira fazer pelos endereços vc troca e usa o paginate por endereços e troca o relacionamento...

Acho que funfa!

Comment: Muito obrigado, Luiz :)! Consegui fazendo assim. Eu não estava  seguindo o padrão da documentação do Laravel, por isso a dificuldade e sei que podemos também fazer este relacionamento de forma diferente da documentação. Muito obrigado!!

Comment: Ontem eu descobri que os relacionamentos funcionam mesmo se não houver uma chave estrangeira programada no banco, pois no meu ambiente de homologação as tabelas não estavam sendo criadas com InnoDB, mas com MyIsan, e quando fui conferir as chaves estrangeiras não estavam no banco, mas os relacionamentos funcionavam... vai entender, Na verdade, entendi que as chaves estrangeiras nada mais são do que os índices mpara deixar os relacionamentos mais rápidos. Fico feliz em ter te ajudado!

Comment: É, eu ainda estou em um nível de início com Laravel/php, mas estou gostando muito. O desenvolvimento é bem mais rápido que Java.